# show that the abc-conjecture implies that $x! + 1 = y^2$, $x \in \mathbb{N}$ has at most finitely many solutions.

Tags: number-theory

show that the abc-conjecture implies that $x! + 1 = y^2$, $x \in \mathbb{N}$ has at most finitely many solutions.

I tried to look at $a= x!, b=1, c=y^2$.

The hints i got:
1)$\Pi_{p\leq n} \text{  } p \leq 4^n$ where $p$ is prime.

2) Note that $1 + \frac{y-1}{2} = \frac{y+1}{2}$

What i tried:

$rad(x!)rad(y) \leq x!y < y^3$. So if we look at the quality we get:

$q(x!,y,1) = \frac{2\log(y)}{\log(rad(x!y))} > \frac{2\log(y)}{3\log(y))} = \frac{2}{3}. $

I am curious if the quality can help us solve the problem but i dn't thinks so.

so looking at $rad(x!)$, we see that this is equal to the product of all primes smaller then $x$, so $rad(x!) \leq 4^x$ by the hint i got.

So $rad(x!)rad(y^2) \leq 4^x y^2$. if i can prove that $4^x \leq y^k$ for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$, i can probably just use the abc conjecture. But the main problem is that i don't see how to get there, any tips?

PS: I have seen a solution with stirlings formula, but i want a solution which uses the hint to have more insights on this question :)

Kees

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$rad(x!)rad(y^2)\leq 4^xy$$
Now
$$y>\sqrt{x!}=c\frac{x^{\frac{x}{2}+\frac{1}{4}}}{e^{\frac{x}{2}}},$$
(here I used Stirling formula)
and for $x>16e$ this quantity is greater than $4^x$.

Comment: hmmmmm, i would not come up with this myself. Is there not an easier way to do this using the hint in 2?